# How to add object to specific place in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am using a library [React simple chatbot](https://lucasbassetti.com.br/react-simple-chatbot/#/docs/chatbot) and add data from database, but the problem is i have array like below

**Array from Database**

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "message": "What is your name?",
    "type": "text",
    "trigger": "2"
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "message": "What is your age?",
    "type": "text",
    "trigger": "3"
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "message": "What is your date of birth?",
    "type": "text",
    "trigger": "1"
}]
```

But i need something like below

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "message": "What is your name?",
    "type": "text",
    "trigger": "2"
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "user": true,
    "trigger": 3
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "message": "What is your age?",
    "type": "text",
    "trigger": "4"
}, {
    "id": 4,
    "user": true,
    "trigger": 5
}, {
    "id": 5,
    "message": "What is your date of birth?",
    "type": "text",
    "trigger": "6"
}, {
    "id": 6,
    "user": true,
    "trigger": 1
}]
```

Please help me to create array like this. I write some code, but doesn't work for me. My code print duplicate ids. **Basically i want to pass object after every object with increment id.**

**Code**

```
  fetch("api_url_here")
        .then((res) => {
          return res.json();
        })
        .then((data) => {
          const steps = data.map((res, index) => {
            return {
              id: index,
              message: res.question,
              type: res.type,
              trigger: res.trigger,
            };
          });
          var array = [];

          var trigger = 1;
          steps.forEach((step, index) => {
            index = index;
            array.push(step);
            if (step.type == "text") {
              array.push({
                id: trigger + 1,
                user: true,
                trigger: trigger,
              });
            }
            trigger++;
          });
          document.getElementById("json").append(JSON.stringify(array));
        })
```

**Current Output**

```
[{
    "id": 0,
    "message": "What is your name?",
    "type": "text",
    "trigger": "2"
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "user": true,
    "trigger": 1
}, {
    "id": 1,
    "message": "What is your age?",
    "type": "text",
    "trigger": "3"
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "user": true,
    "trigger": 2
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "message": "What is your date of birth?",
    "type": "text",
    "trigger": "1"
}, {
    "id": 4,
    "user": true,
    "trigger": 3
}]
```

Any solution appreciated!

Comment: If you have the correct array with bad values for id and trigger, a final map()  will do the trick. What's your current output?

Comment: Let me update my question

Comment: Notice an edit in my answer to improve the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to add this as a final step to correct the id and trigger

```js
const almost = [{
  "id": 0,
  "message": "What is your name?",
  "type": "text",
  "trigger": "2"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "user": true,
  "trigger": 1
}, {
  "id": 1,
  "message": "What is your age?",
  "type": "text",
  "trigger": "3"
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "user": true,
  "trigger": 2
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "message": "What is your date of birth?",
  "type": "text",
  "trigger": "1"
}, {
  "id": 4,
  "user": true,
  "trigger": 3
}]

const final = almost.map( (obj,index) => {
  const newObj = {};
  Object.assign(newObj,
    obj,
    {
      "id":index+1,
      "trigger": index+2
    }
  );
  return newObj;
});
final[final.length-1].trigger = 1;

console.log(final)
```

EDIT: to make it clear, your code would look like:

```js
fetch("api_url_here")
        .then((res) => {
          return res.json();
        })
        .then((data) => {
          const steps = data.map((res, index) => {
            return {
              id: index,
              message: res.question,
              type: res.type,
              trigger: res.trigger,
            };
          });
          var array = [];

          var trigger = 1;
          steps.forEach((step, index) => {
            index = index;
            array.push(step);
            if (step.type == "text") {
              array.push({
                id: trigger + 1,
                user: true,
                trigger: trigger,
              });
            }
            trigger++;
          });
          
          array = array.map( (obj,index) => {
          const newObj = {};
          Object.assign(newObj,
            obj,
            {
              "id":index+1,
              "trigger": index+2
            }
          );
          return newObj;
        });
          array[array.length-1].trigger = 1;
          
          
          document.getElementById("json").append(JSON.stringify(array));
        })
```